# Discord bot error - SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in dicord.j sand using sequelize and sqlite to make the databse. it has a currency system for when someone posts in a specific channel and I am receiving this error `SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users` although in the error it doesnt give a clue to where I am going wrong here is the main.js file:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Users, CurrencyShop } = require('F:/Users/User/Desktop/SuccessBot/dbObjects.js');
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const async = require('async')
const currency = new Discord.Collection();
const token = ''
var CHANNEL_ID = '733612021869838387';
var LEADERBOARD_ID = '734352105481044019'
 
const prefix = '-';

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});

client.once('ready', async () => {
    const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
    storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
    console.log('Radar Success is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    currency.add(message.author.id, 1);

    if (message.channel.id === CHANNEL_ID) {

        memberTag = message.member.id
        var score = '1'

        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        //return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
        return message.channel.send('<@' + memberTag + `> Thanks for posting success! Your score is now ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
    }

    if (message.channel.id === LEADERBOARD_ID) {
        return message.channel.send(
            currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
                .filter(user => client.users.cache.has(user.user_id))
                .first(10)
                .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.cache.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
                .join('\n'),
            { code: true }
        );
    }
 

});
 
client.login(token);
```

I then have a file to store the different users, store their items and store the shop:
Users.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('users', {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        balance: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
    });
};
```

UserItems.js:

```
    return sequelize.define('user_item', {
        user_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        item_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        amount: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            'default': 0,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
    });
};
```

CurrencyShop.js

```
    return sequelize.define('currency_shop', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
        },
        cost: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
    });
};
```

I then set up the sequelize database using, dbInit.js :

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

const CurrencyShop = sequelize.import('models/CurrencyShop');
sequelize.import('models/Users');
sequelize.import('models/UserItems');

const force = process.argv.includes('--force') || process.argv.includes('-f');

sequelize.sync({ force }).then(async () => {
    const shop = [
        CurrencyShop.upsert({ name: 'Tea', cost: 1 }),
        CurrencyShop.upsert({ name: 'Coffee', cost: 2 }),
        CurrencyShop.upsert({ name: 'Cake', cost: 5 }),
    ];
    await Promise.all(shop);
    console.log('Database synced');
    sequelize.close();
}).catch(console.error);
```

and dbObjects.js:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

const Users = sequelize.import('./models/Users');
const CurrencyShop = sequelize.import('./models/CurrencyShop');
const UserItems = sequelize.import('./models/UserItems');

UserItems.belongsTo(CurrencyShop, { foreignKey: 'item_id', as: 'item' });

Users.prototype.addItem = async function(item) {
    const useritem = await UserItems.findOne({
        where: { user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id },
    });

    if (useritem) {
        useritem.amount += 1;
        return useritem.save();
    }

    return UserItems.create({ user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id, amount: 1 });
};

Users.prototype.getItems = function() {
    return UserItems.findAll({
        where: { user_id: this.user_id },
        include: ['item'],
    });
};

module.exports = { Users, CurrencyShop, UserItems };
```

I know this is a very broad question as I have literally supplied all my code but if someone out there is very experienced in this it may be a quick fix, looking forward to an answer!

EDIT: I left my bot token there and someone destroyed my server, thanks guys love you all, my fault tho I guess. An answer would still be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's a SQL error, your database does not have a `users` table

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the database I guess?

Execute `node dbInit.js` to create the database tables.

https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#initialize-database